# How can i find the AT24C256 reg_addr?

Tags: i2c, c, eeprom

For **i2c to eeprom (at24c256)** how can I find the *device address* and register address?

```
i2c_result_t i2c_hw_write(void *priv, uint8_t dev_addr, uint16_t reg_addr,
    uint8_t reg_addr_size, uint8_t *data, uint8_t ndata_bytes) {

  I2C_HW_Driver *i2cd = priv;
  
  /* Set i2c context */
  i2cd->dev_addr = dev_addr | I2C_HW_WRITE;
  i2cd->reg_addr.W = reg_addr;
  i2cd->data = data;
  i2cd->ndata_bytes = ndata_bytes;

  if (i2cd->i2c_tagp->IBSR.B.IBB == 1U) {
    i2cd->result = I2C_ERROR_BUS_BUSY;
    return I2C_ERROR_BUS_BUSY;
  }

  if (reg_addr_size == I2C_16_BIT_REG_ADDRESS) {
    i2cd->state = I2C_SEND_REG_ADDRESS_HIGH;
  } else {
    i2cd->state = I2C_SEND_REG_ADDRESS_LOW;
  }

  i2cd->operation = I2C_HW_WRITE;
  i2cd->result = I2C_ERROR_TRANSFER_IN_PROGRESS;

  /* Transmit the device address */
  i2cd->i2c_tagp->IBCR.B.MS = (uint8_t)i2cd->mode;
  i2cd->i2c_tagp->IBCR.B.TX = 1;
  i2cd->i2c_tagp->IBDR.R = i2cd->dev_addr;

  /* Wait, with timeout, for transfer completion */
  wait_for_transfer_completion(i2cd);

  return(i2cd->result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You open the datasheet and look up possible device addresses and then look at schematics which of the device addresses it is set to.

Register address functions the as memory address, since the chip has no registers. Or all the register addresses contain memory. Which ever way you want to think it.